# How to correctly handle stochastic tasks on `FORK` clusters in `R`?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, random-seed

Running the following code in a ***clean*** `R` session, on a Linux or Mac, works as expected:

```
# A function.
wrapper <- function() {
    # Create backend.
    backend <- parallel::makeCluster(7, "FORK")

    # Some task.
    compute <- function(backend) {
        return(
            parallel::parSapply(backend, 1:7, function(x) {
                # Sleep.
                Sys.sleep(0.5)

                # Perform something stochastic.
                rnorm(1)
            })
        )
    }

    # Compute.
    result <- compute(backend)

    # Stop the backend.
    parallel::stopCluster(backend)

    return(result)
}

# Running the function.
for (i in 1:3) print(wrapper())

# Example output.
# [1] -1.0788369  0.3272692 -0.7901025 -0.5189769 -1.4266314 -0.7013846 -0.1463723
# [1] -0.1781885 -2.6047250 -0.4323422 -0.1111752 -1.0172990 -0.2419793  0.9989368
# [1]  0.1805763 -1.7888074  1.3219294  1.0432285  1.0664767 -1.1183905  0.7122091
```

I suspect this is the case because in a ***clean*** `R` session a `.Random.seed` is yet to be created. Therefore, when `makeCluster` forks the main process each branch will initialize their own `.Random.seed` based on the clock time (i.e., as indicated in [section six in the documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/parallel/doc/parallel.pdf) of the `parallel` package).

The moment the `.Random.seed` gets created in the main process (e.g., say by running `rnorm(1)`), things start to break because now all branches of the fork have the same starting point. This results in identical results, which is not what I need. For example:

```
# Do something stochastic to create the `.Random.seed` variable in the main process.
rnorm(1)

# Run the wrapper that will now see the `.Random.seed` variable.
for (i in 1:3) print(wrapper())

# Example output.
# [1] 0.2724477 0.2724477 0.2724477 0.2724477 0.2724477 0.2724477 0.2724477
# [1] 0.2724477 0.2724477 0.2724477 0.2724477 0.2724477 0.2724477 0.2724477
# [1] 0.2724477 0.2724477 0.2724477 0.2724477 0.2724477 0.2724477 0.2724477
```

I tried to use the `iseed` argument of `parallel::clusterSetRNGStream` as the documentation indicates:

> An integer to be supplied to set.seed, or NULL not to set reproducible seeds.

But adding `parallel::clusterSetRNGStream(backend, iseed = NULL)` to my wrapper function had no effect.

How can I make a `FORK` cluster where each branch is guaranteed to have a different starting position in the pseudo-random number generating sequence? I am not interested in setting a seed to reproduce results.

Comment: FWIW, if you use `future::plan("cluster", workers = backend)` and `y <- future.apply::future_sapply(..., future.seed = TRUE)` instead of `y <- parallel::parSapply(backend, ...)`, you'll automatically get reproducible parallel random numbers, regardless of parallel backend and the number of parallel workers.

Comment: Thanks, @HenrikB, I would definitely use the `future` package, but I am constrained to work with code that relies heavily on `parallel::parSapply` calls. I cannot modify those calls, all I have control over is the creation of the backend, which I can pass to those calls (i.e., hence the reason why in my example above I used the function `wrapper` to wrap `compute`).

Comment: @HenrikB, I found a workaround, but I am not familiar with parallel processing in `R` and I am afraid it might result in some hard to debug side effects. Would it be possible to take a quick look at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68638116/5252007? I appreciate it.